# Objective-C: help me parse this JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I have the following JSON object being returned from my webserver. I can't figure out how to parse it... I basically want to extract the uname and the profilePic for each of the drivers (there are two drivers in this example). I'm not interested in the rest of the stuff.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "0": {
        "uname": "Eamorr",
        "fname": "Bill",
        "lname": "Byrne",
        "phoneNumber": "087-2342404",
        "roofSignNumber": "32984",
        "reputation": 0,
        "vehicleMake": "Toyota",
        "vehicleModel": "Carina",
        "vehicleNumPassengers": "4",
        "profilePic": "XE7F654O05RC3I33P44A",
        "online": 1,
        "lat": "52.27114461",
        "lng": "-9.70294471",
        "status": "done!",
        "sex": "M",
        "picList": ["W725CY1XR63PW480Z694", "XBA2078W4Z3JROQMSN16", "0H0XDD27J9J9RV28KKR4", "84G09NCP537G1KM6O4R8", "FM12F2J12AWL8C8XX2F5", "5AU4FLJ50PN0R210AP8J", "5588ORG95RF10B757NY7", "4z54cz5c565410r2wq2u", "3502IXTI31MSX6Z01NWC", "XE7F654O05RC3I33P44A", "A828K8M0E5576C1AK6HU", "M5EHX8MQMHZ6PJ1NNYH7", "8RIS3245542E2I9TLOD4", "3V5F7HNZNN642O29347Y", "YU2CT34A7769XG2LV38G"],
        "last5comments": [{
            "comment": "asdf2",
            "fromUname": "Anonymous",
            "time": 1314036666
        }, {
            "comment": "qwerty",
            "fromUname": "Eamorr",
            "time": 1314550970
        }, {
            "comment": "qwerty",
            "fromUname": "Eamorr",
            "time": 1314551143
        }, {
            "comment": "hi",
            "fromUname": "Eamorr2",
            "time": 1315157494
        }, {
            "comment": "Hello",
            "fromUname": "Anonymous",
            "time": 1315394983
        }],
        "numPagesComments": 13
    },
    "1": {
        "uname": "Eamorr2",
        "fname": "Steve",
        "lname": "McCloskey",
        "phoneNumber": "087-3234404",
        "roofSignNumber": "32431",
        "reputation": 0,
        "vehicleMake": "Toyota",
        "vehicleModel": "avensis",
        "vehicleNumPassengers": "4",
        "profilePic": -1,
        "online": "0",
        "lat": "52.28783634",
        "lng": "-9.66791791",
        "status": "",
        "sex": "M",
        "picList": [],
        "last5comments": [{
            "comment": "asdf",
            "fromUname": "Anonymous",
            "time": 1296655686
        }, {
            "comment": "I'm off in the middle of the Atlantic again",
            "fromUname": "Anonymous",
            "time": 1296843759
        }, {
            "comment": "Hi",
            "fromUname": "Eamorr",
            "time": 1299098148
        }, {
            "comment": "Hi",
            "fromUname": "Eamorr",
            "time": 1299098148
        }, {
            "comment": "Hi",
            "fromUname": "Eamorr",
            "time": 1299098148
        }],
        "numPagesComments": 2
    }
}
```

And here's what I've tried to code up (to no avail...):

```
//NSDictionary *obj=[parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:nil];
        NSArray *obj=[parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:nil];

        NSLog([obj objectAtIndex:0]);
        /*for(int i=0;i<obj.count;i++){
            NSDictionary *driver=[obj objectAtIndex:i];
            for (NSDictionary *dict in driver) {
                [unames addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"uname"]];
                [profilePics addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"profilePic"]];
            }
        }
```

I hope someone can help.

---

Solution:

```
SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
        //NSDictionary *obj=[parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:nil];
        NSDictionary *obj=[parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:nil];

        for(int i=0;i<[obj count];i++){
            NSDictionary *obj2=[obj objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
             NSLog(@"%@",[obj2 objectForKey:@"uname"]);
        }
```

Comment: What is your "parser" object? What class? How do you create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SBJSON https://github.com/stig/json-framework

```
SBJSON *jsonReader = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDictionary *responce = [jsonReader objectWithString:[request responseString]];

NSString *uName1 = [[responce objectForKey:@"0"] objectForKey:@"uname"];
NSString *image1 = [[responce objectForKey:@"0"] objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
```

Comment: Hey, I'm using SBJSON. The problem is that the two drivers are in an array, not an NSDictionary

Comment: They are not, based on the representation you posted above they are NSDictionaries and the solution posted by @Vladislav is correct.

Comment: They are not in Array. They are in a Dictionary.

Comment: I just realised this... Updated OP with solution.